# WooCommerce use Secondary PHP File (Recalling Template)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How am I supposed to call a secondary PHP file? Here is my code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_simfree_product_tab' );

function woo_simfree_product_tab( $tabs ) {

global $post;
if( function_exists('get_product') ){
$product = get_product( $post->ID );
if( $product->is_type( 'grouped' ) ){
        $tabs['simfree-plans'] = array( 'title' => __( 'SIM Free', 'woocommerce' ), 'priority' => 20, 'callback' => 'woo_simfree_product_tab_content' );
    return $tabs;
} else {
    return $tabs;
}
}

}

function woo_simfree_product_tab_content() {

require get_template_directory() . "/custom-groups/grouped-simfree.php";

}
```

The problem is fetching the file right here... (3rd line from the bottom)

```
require get_template_directory() . "/custom-groups/grouped-simfree.php";
```

This does not work and causes strange behaviour. I have a custom PHP file I want to load in this tab I have created (grouped-simfree.php) but I don't know how to make it run.

What is the correct way to load a custom PHP file in wordpress from a function on a hook?

---

EDIT: (What's wrong with this picture?) I actually solved this problem years ago but now I've come back to the same problem but the same solution is not working for some reason. source (my question from 2014): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233440/woocommerce-woocommerce-grouped-add-to-cart-function

```
function woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart2() {
    global $product;
    wc_get_template( get_template_directory() . '/custom-groups/grouped-simfree.php', array(
        'grouped_product'    => $product,
        'grouped_products'   => $product->get_children(),
        'quantites_required' => false
    ) );
}

function woo_simfree_product_tab_content() {
    woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart2();

}
```

---

EDIT 2
If I move the custom template into the woocommerce plugin templates folder.

@Reigel this works but now im gonna lose the template when ever I update woocommerce I just realised this is what I did a couple years ago and now I realise why my site crashed because the templates were overwritten during a woocommerce update

```
function woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart2() {
    global $product;
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/grouped-simfree.php', array(
        'grouped_product'    => $product,
        'grouped_products'   => $product->get_children(),
        'quantites_required' => false
    ) );
}

function woo_simfree_product_tab_content() {

    woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart2();

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working? and where is this file located? do you have this code on your functions.php?

Comment: Yeah this is my functions.php code, the file is located in my child theme folder at "/custom-groups/grouped-simfree.php" it causes my product tabs to not respond and my page scrolls when I click one of them but doesn't switch tabs - is this the correct way to use a custom php file?

Comment: can you include your codes of `grouped-simfree.php`... just paste it on pastebin.com or something and give us the link...

Comment: it's just a moded version of grouped.php from woocommerce I know it works its an exact clone of an already working template I have functioning on the site except filters through a different attribute in a foreach loop what im trying to do is have one tab filter through all products in the group and show only products with attribute A and have the second tab filter through products with attribute B, checkout the original grouped.php from woocommerce here I just modded the HTML https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/grouped.php

Comment: I just had a thought that maybe im calling grouped-simfree.php but missing out on something     `woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart();` provides.

Comment: is there anyway to pass an argument to       `woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart();`
to tell it to use a different template but then id have 2       `woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart();`
running on the same page would that conflict?

Comment: or maybe running two of them already is causing them to conflict

Comment: does anyone know if the 3rd line from the bottom is the correct way to call the custom template as i thought that was the problem?

Comment: Is it a child theme?

Comment: `wc_get_template` will locate files inside `woocommerce` folder in your theme or `woocommerce/templates/` folder in the plugin...

Comment: what should i replace it with?

Comment: @Skatox your 100% right... if I load my custom template into the templates directory in the woocommerce plugin then change the path in my custom functions `wc_get_template` it works but now my problem is if I update my site the template will be lost - any ideas??

Comment: do your edits on your theme... not on the plugin...

Comment: wc_get_template will look for the file in your theme first then on the plugin if not found

Comment: create a folder named `woocommerce` in your theme... this is the equivalent of `woocommerce/templates` folder in the plugin...

Comment: @Scott use the answer I gave, you should have a woocommerce folder in your child theme, and do ALL modifications in child theme, so if parent or woocommerce is udpated, it won't affect your changes.

Comment: thanks guys sorted it

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `get_stylesheet_directory()` to include your file, if it's a child theme do something like this:

```
require get_stylesheet_directory() . "/custom-groups/grouped-simfree.php";
```

The file should be at **wp-content/themes/your-child-theme/custom-groups/grouped-simfree.php**