# Separating the register and login page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to split the registration and login page in a Wordpress site with WooCommerce activated. I found some ressources [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962909/how-to-create-separate-log-in-and-registration-pages-in-woocommerce).

However this is not working for me. I've copied the woocommerce/templates/my-account/form-login.php in the `child-theme/woocommerce/my-account/form-login-single.php`
Then I've created a new `child-theme/woocommerce/my-account/form-login.php` where I've put the code in the message :

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['action']) == 'register' ) {
    wc_get_template( 'myaccount/form-register.php' );
} else {
    wc_get_template( 'myaccount/form-login-single.php' );
}
```

The results is simple that the "my-account" page is displaying nothing, neither the login, not the register. Even if I tries to access the my-site.com/my-account?action=register, nothing happens.

It seems that the solution is broken. What can I do to separate the login and register forms in WooCommerce ?

Comment: So I found some ideas on this post, which is basically that the use of `wc_get_template` is a bad idea of I try to use functions in my child theme. I could manage to get the split between a copy of the  form-login and a tweaked code containing only the part on register. I'm not sure if this is the right approach. could someone comment ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405279/woocommerce-use-secondary-php-file-recalling-template

Comment: You might find this resource helpful https://teamtreehouse.com/community/woocommerce-login-registration-on-separate-pages.  It looks like he did the same thing you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that worked for me was running a jQuery function to grab the URL and split it at every ' / ' - working out that the URL string that needed to change would be the 4th index. (you can use the code below)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    url = url.split("/");
    if (url[4] == "log-in") // You can set url[] according to slash parameter wise
    {
        $("#customer_login .u-column2").remove(); //Remove Registration Div
    }
    if (url[4] == "register") {
        $("#customer_login .u-column1").remove(); // Remove Login Div
    }
    console.log(url);
});
```

What this does is when the 4th index of the url string is equal too Log-In (or what your page is called) then it will remove the 'register' form. Then when the opposite happens in the following block, if the 4th index of the URL is equal too register, it will remove the log in form :)

Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: Obviously take out the console log ^^

Answer (score 0):

ALTERNATIVELY 
I just encountered a problem after leaving the login/register and was working on forgot/reset password. The code ended up not working for the register, if the above hasn't helped fix your problem check this link below.

https://sangkrit.net/create-separate-login-registration-pages-woocommerce/

In the second part it talks about using a plugin called WooCommerce LogIn/Sign Up lite, It comes with short codes to allow you to separate them. For me personally I just changed the shortcode on the 'register' page left the others with what they were and it works perfectly again :)